# How to add Google Talk (~ Hangouts) to Pidgin chat client?

Tags: google-talk, google-hangouts, pidgin

There is a [hangups](https://github.com/tdryer/hangups) plug-in, which supports (if I understand correctly) Google Talk (~ Hangouts). How do I add it to my Pidgin chat client?

Comment: That appears to be a library and its own client. It isn't a pidgin plugin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a comprehensive step-by-step guide on
**How to compile and install Pidgin and make it work with Google Talk (~ Hangouts) on Linux**:
The differences between Hangouts and Google Talk you will find on this page:
https://support.google.com/a/answer/4564211
1. Enable 2-Step Verification on this page:
 https://accounts.google.com/SmsAuthConfig
[image: 2-Step Verification]
2. Generate a new App password for Pidgin on this page, select *Other* and name it however:
 https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords
[image: App password]
3. Install the latest version of Pidgin for your system from this page:
https://pidgin.im/download/ or from repository of your Linux distribution or compile it from source (or for Max OS X they recommend using http://adium.im/)
4. To avoid security bugs, you should often check if your Linux distribution repository contains the latest version available, which you may check on this page https://pidgin.im/news/security/
5. If you choose to compile, you simply install the dependencies, download and compile the code, and install Pidgin as follows:

```
$ sudo apt-get build-dep pidgin
$ sudo apt-get source pidgin
$ tar xjvf pidgin-2.x.y.tar.bz2
$ cd pidgin-2.x.y
$ ./configure && make && sudo make install
```

Alternately, e.g. on Debian, where you (by default) have to *su* instead of *sudo* (haven't tested myself, correct me if I'm wrong):

```
$ su -
# apt-get build-dep pidgin
# apt-get source pidgin
# exit
$ tar xjvf pidgin-2.x.y.tar.bz2
$ cd pidgin-2.x.y
$ ./configure && make
$ su -
# make install
```

If it fails for some reason, please refer to this page:
https://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/Installing%20Pidgin#WhycantIcompilePidgin
6. Right-click the system-tray icon of Pidgin and choose *Accounts*.
7. Add or modify your *Google Talk* account to have *Username* without @gmail.com or your own domain.
8. If you have your own domain for Google account, fill in the *Domain* field, otherwise there should be *gmail.com* present by default (without @).
9. The *Resource* is an XMPP specific thing that allows one to use several clients for the same account. Under normal circumstances leave blank.
10. Fill in the *Password* generated in step two.
11. Optional, but convenient, if on a secure computer, is ticking *Remember password*.
12. *Local alias* leave blank.
13. It should look like this:
[image: Adding Google Talk account to Pidgin]
14. On Advanced tab make sure you have *Require encryption* chosen and disabled *plaintext*.
15. Note, that after you save these settings, the protocol will automatically change to *XMPP*, which is currently available to third-party applications like Pidgin.